# Data driven XML generation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, template-engine

For one of my projects I have a XML file containing templates, that should generate plots for a GUI. The user can write its own XML templates and apply it to the currently load data.

The simplified XML template file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Templates>
  <Template name="template">
    <PlotWindow name="PlotWindow">
      <Title>My title</Title>
      <For>
        <Var>%Variable%</Var>
        <Plot name="%Variable%">
          <Item>f(%Variable%)</Item>
        </Plot>
      </For>
    </PlotWindow>
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

The `For`-tag should be replaced by all the data contained in `%Variable%`. The data itself is defined in a second XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Var name="%Variable%">
    <Item>Test</Item>
    <Item>MyVar</Item>
    <Item>ABC</Item>
  </Var>
</Data>
```

`%Variable%` should be iterated through `Test`, `MyVar` and `ABC`. The desired output should be a third XML file shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Result>
  <PlotWindow name="PlotWindow">
    <Title>My title</Title>
    <Plot name="Test">
      <Item>f(Test)</Item>
    </Plot>
    <Plot name="MyVar">
      <Item>f(MyVar)</Item>
    </Plot>
    <Plot name="ABC">
      <Item>f(ABC)</Item>
    </Plot>
  </PlotWindow>
</Result>
```

It should be possible to get such a result by some kind of XSLT file.

What will this file look like?

Comment: Recommendations are close to off-topic in SO as you know, and nobody will show you "how the xslt will look like" by building it for you - but IMHO it should be possible with xslt.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Just removed the last part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how detailed your examples are (can there be multiple `Var` elements in `Data`? Multiple `For` elements in `PlotWindow`?), but given the current content this can be a solution.

Assuming the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Data>
        <Var name="%Variable%">
            <Item>Test</Item>
            <Item>MyVar</Item>
            <Item>ABC</Item>
        </Var>
    </Data>
    <Templates>
        <Template name="template">
            <PlotWindow name="PlotWindow">
                <Title>My title</Title>
                <For>
                    <Var>%Variable%</Var>
                    <Plot name="%Variable%">
                        <Item>f(%Variable%)</Item>
                    </Plot>
                </For>
            </PlotWindow>
        </Template>
    </Templates>
</root>
```

(I guess the `Data` is in a different file. If so, use `document()` function to load it at the line `<xsl:for-each select="//Data">`.)

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"  />

    <xsl:template match="Templates">
        <Result>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PlotWindow|Title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="For">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="./Var/text()"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="//Data">
                <xsl:for-each select="Var[@name=$name]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                        <xsl:variable name="plotname" select="./text()"/>
                        <Plot name="{$plotname}">
                            <Item>f(<xsl:value-of select="$plotname"/>)</Item>
                        </Plot>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data|Var|Item"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
    <PlotWindow name="PlotWindow">
        <Title>My title</Title>
        <Plot name="Test">
            <Item>f(Test)</Item>
        </Plot>
        <Plot name="MyVar">
            <Item>f(MyVar)</Item>
        </Plot>
        <Plot name="ABC">
            <Item>f(ABC)</Item>
        </Plot>
    </PlotWindow>
</Result>
```